# how to repair corrupted pendrive

Tags: windows-7, usb, memory, usb-flash-drive

My pendrive is hp c350 with 16gb memory. 
It was working quite well before few weeks. 
One day after improper ejection it was not working properly. 
Whatever file I put into the pendrive is becoming corrupted. And many times pendrive shows gb's of memory used without any files in it. I tired formatting it with many options on windows and on many PC's. I tried using diskpart clean command and cmd format and normal format, nothing is working. Could you guide me into getting my pendrive to normal working state?

Comment: Throw it away & get a new one. They're not worth fighting once they start to fail.

Comment: Assuming you have deleted and recreated the partition table, I agree with previous commenter to replace it... at well under $6 USD for 16GB USB 3.0 drive, throw it away and buy a new one because it's not worth the hassle. The device has already exhibited a failure, do you want to trust it with any data?

Comment: Are you **safely removing** the drive after using it, every time? If you're writing files then just yanking it out, you could be corrupting the files yourself. Sometimes write caches haven't finished writing. `fsck` / `chkdsk` should fix the filesystem if it's a one-time error, but formatting should "reset" it...  And testing it on different hardware (as you say you've done with "many PC's") is a good way to verify that it's the drive itself that's bad, and not just a bad USB port or cable etc.

Answer (score 1):

If it's a hardware failure, there is nothing you can do.  Throw it away.  If it's a filesystem failure (which, based on your description, it could be), you should do a byte-level write-all-zeroes erase and then reformat it and see if it will behave.  You can use a tool such as [Lowvel](http://www.lowlevelformat.info/using-lowvel.aspx) to do the erasing.  It may also show you if there are bad blocks (but it may not since pendrives work a bit differently with failures).

As noted by @Tetsujin & others in the comments, if it's even remotely possible that it's a hardware failure and not software, your best option is to discard the device and replace it.  If it's still under warranty, return it to the place you purchased it and ask for a replacement.

Comment: now I tried lowvel, still the same problem persists.

Comment: Then it's most likely a hardware failure.  If it's still under warranty, get a replacement.  If not, throw it in the garbage.

Comment: Ok. Then I got to get a new one. Thank you for your answer @Mekki MacAulay